# Are people born under an eclipse considered inauspicious or ill-fated?

Tags: belief, astrology, eclipse, omens

I have heard, that children born under eclipse (Surya-Grahan, & Chandra-Grahan) are considered ill-fated as per the Jyotish-shastras?

Is it true as per scriptures, specifically the astrological treatises?

People generally say, being born under an eclipse is an ill-omen for the child's family? Do scriptures say anything to that effect?

If it's true does the effect varies with the type of grahan, like Surya - Grahan born people considered more ill-fated compared to Chandra-Grahan born, or vice-versa, etc.?

Are there some remedies to such a birth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**

A person born under eclipse is considered ill-fated, as per the Brihat-Parashara-Hora Shastra. The text, however, doesn't mention which amongst the Lunar or Solar eclipse birth will be more inauspicious.

> [Chapter 91](https://archive.org/details/BPHSEnglish/BPHS%20-%202%20RSanthanam/page/n533/mode/2up) - Remedies for Birth in Eclipses
>
> ९१ - अथ ग्रहणजातशान्त्यध्यायः, बृहत्पाराशरहोराशास्त्रम्
>
> सूर्येन्दुग्रहणे काले येषां जन्म भवेद् द्विज । व्याधिः कष्टं च
> दारिद्र्यं तेषां मृत्युभयं भवेत् ॥ १ ॥
>
> > 1. The Sage said. O Brahmin! **A person, whose birth takes place at the time of the solar, or lunar eclipse, suffers from ailments, distress,
> >    and poverty and faces the danger of death. Therefore I am going to
> >    describe for the benefit of mankind the remedial measures, required to
> >    be undertaken to nullify the above evil effects.**
>
> English Translation by Dr. R. Santhanam

#### Remedies:

The Complete Chapter 91 of the text, enlists various remedies, as per the ascendant and the other aspects of the Horoscope of the afflicted person, I'm briefly summarizing them here -

> - Preparing the idols of the Sun in Gold, Moon in Silver, and Rahu in Lead. Also preparing a gold idol of the [deity of the
>   Nakshatra](https://archive.org/details/BPHSEnglish/BPHS%20-%201%20RSanthanam/page/n27/mode/2up)
>   in which the person is born.
> - Proper consecration of the above idols, and offering appropriate items which are dear to those deities, depending upon Solar or Lunar
>   Eclipse.
> - Worshipping the deities with appropriate mantras and performing a Homam thereafter, with proper Vedic injunctions, followed by
>   sprinkling the consecrated holy water which was kept in the *Homam
>   puja-kalash* (pot).
> - Providing appropriate *daan-dakshina* to the priest and feeding the Brahminas, to the best of one's capacities.